# Database error in ASP.NET MVC3 EF4.1 code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, windows-phone-7, azure

Hi i have a working app that uses an attached mdf file with the following connect string :

```
<add name="SqlDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;User Instance=true;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\WPCloudApp26.mdf;Initial Catalog=WPCloudApp26;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am using a Windows phone cloud application template and i have azure storage emulator running on my pc

everything works fine, until i do the following steps for the first time:

1. i want to view the database so i double click the app_data/WPCloudApp26.mdf file through visual studio when the app is not running. when i double click it, the db opens up under data connections in the server explorer pane and i can see the database and all the tables. so far everything good
2. I am done viewing the db, so i close the connection by right clicking --> close connection.
3. i want to run the app again, and when i run it all hell breaks loose. i get the following error message:

> One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If
>   you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the
>   correct files.  If this is an existing database, the file may be
>   corrupted and should be restored from a backup.\r\nCannot open
>   database \"WPCloudApp26\" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>   SERVICE'.\r\nLog file 'C:\Users\michael\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WPCloudApp26\WPCloudApp26\WPCloudApp26.Web\App_Data\WPCloudApp26.ldf'
>   does not match the primary file.  It may be from a different database
>   or the log may have been rebuilt previously.

the exception is thrown on the method `var firstItem = context.SqlSampleData.FirstOrDefault();`

Thats it, no matter what i do, i can't run the app again. this is driving me crazy since the only thing to help is to create a new solution with a different name (thats why i got to number 26)

What is going on ? why is this happening only after the first time i try to view the database in visual studio ?

**Edit**
i have noticed that changing the initial catalog and mdf file in the connection string solves the problem. So where are the remnants of the db name are saved ?  how can i clean up old leftovers ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to open a .MDF file that is attached to SQL Server Express. It will probably break the consistency between the .MDF and the log file.
Connect to the SQL Server Express server using the Server Explorer, or SQL Server Management Studio. (There's a free version of it for Express as well)

If you really want to open the .MDF in Visual Studio, then detach the DB from SQL Server Express first.

Comment: thanks, can you please explain in more details why is this happening ? why is there an option to view it through Visual Studio if they know that it breaks it. i am beginning to really hate this toolkit and VS

Comment: another question, when i delete the project from the harddrive and start again with the same name, it still doesnt work, even when there is no memory of the mdf file anywhere. do you have an explanation for this ?

Comment: Michael, you should really look at SQL Server as a... Server. As such, you as a developer and/or an end user should hardly never bother about its internals and the files it uses. I can't see why you as a developer would want to open the .MDF file by yourself. What benefit does that give you? You can to all maintenance and other tasks by connect as a client to it using SSMS.

Comment: To your second question; well that doesn't change a thing really. As far as I'm concerned the world could disappear and come back and you still are facing the core problem: why do you want to mess with SQL Server's .MDF file?

Comment: i am just looking for a way to see what my app wrote in the database, and preferably do it in the cozy environment of my IDE. this looked like the way that i should see the db from VS. I will try SSMS instead. as for the second question, you didn't really answer it, as i can't create a new project with the same name now and use it the right way as you suggested. therefor i am assuming the remnants of the db is left somewhere on the drive that i am not aware of. do you know how i can erase all memory of it and start over ? thanks.

Comment: "you didn't really answer it". Well pardon me sir. I will do my best to oblige to your needs better. I'm guessing you are testing with IIS, and therefore you may have to delete your web application as well. it's difficult to say since you haven't described your setup properly. But believe me, there's nothing magical happening behind the scenes as you allude to by saying "left somewhere" and "erase all memory". If the file is deleted, it is deleted, you don't have to delete it "more". Use a dir myfile.mdf /s from c:\ and you shall find it.